# Excel - VBA : Userform.Label won't change

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform

My VBA program processes some operations on an input typed by the user and eventually gives back a result.

At some point, I want to have some userform showing up and "adjusting" the research. For example, if the user typed a state and a city which doesn't fit, it would show "Did you mean *city* in *state* ? ". Then, clicking on yes would take into account the modification, clicking no wouldn't change anything.

I have tried this, as found in some tutorials :

```
city = sMain.Range("J12").Value
province = sMain.Range("J6").Value
provinceSugg = sCurrent.Cells(p, db_column).Value

If province = "" And city <> "" Then
UserForm2.Show
UserForm2.Label1 = "Do you mean : " & city & " in " & provinceSugg
Else
End If
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all, whatever text I write for Label1 and whatever way of writing I use (Label1.Caption = , Userform2.Label1.Caption = , Label1 = , etc.), still no change.

Thanks for helping me to fix this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the caption before showing the form...like this:

```
city = sMain.Range("J12").Value
province = sMain.Range("J6").Value
provinceSugg = sCurrent.Cells(p, db_column).Value

If province = "" And city <> "" Then
UserForm2.Label1 = "Do you mean : " & city & " in " & provinceSugg
UserForm2.Show
Else
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use vbModeless ..

```
If province = "" And city <> "" Then
  UserForm2.Show vbModeless
  UserForm2.Label1 = "Do you mean : " & city & " in " & provinceSugg
Else

End If
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, sous2817's solution works as well and was given first so I accepted it but i appreciate your solution also.

Comment: @Phalanx .It's OK .. but you have to know that with 'vbModeless' you can change the label caption .. again and again .. :P